# Unable to fetch value from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA database in spark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a test account for snowflake. I can able to a fetch data from Python but unable to fetch it from Pyspark. Error is showing like unable to create a stage for shared DB. How the stage is creating in Python-snowflake connector?

Answer (score 1):

i think the python connector creates a temp stage for the results in S3
you can see that when you run the connector in debug mode